# Sample size calculation for population that does not follow normal distribution

Tags: sample-size, experiment-design, statistical-power, ab-test

I have a website with over 2 million product pages.

I plan to make some risky changes to the product pages that will either make or brake the volume of traffic.

I plan to run a randomized controlled experiment with these changes.

Because the changes are so risky the sample needs to be as low as it possible can.

The problem is that the products do not follow a normal distribution for traffic. (sharp drop-off, long tail)

I have tried transforming the data (log, sqrt, box-cox, johnson) but without any succes.

I've done of bit of research about how to calculate sample size for this specific case and I think that the following formula applies:

$N = 1 + 2C (\frac{s}{d})^2$

Where:

N - sample size needed

C - constant derived from Alpha and 1-Beta.
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/PQp6jg8y7Gf_VLztkHOIlRkb1c8oZnwxxvVxg5IBBr_gkH2vsb4S6mnAaFqv6d5MIgieoA=s170

s - standard deviation

d - minimum observable difference

But I think that this implies normal distribution of the population.

How do you take into account a non-normal distribution of the population when calculating sample size, for randomized controlled experiments?

Or this is automatically taken care of by the high standard deviation?

Thanks in advance for the help.